# XML/HTML special character codes

Tags: html, xml

Is there an official name for the character codes, the codes that represent & as & in order to differentiate between the text character and the coding use of it, used in XML and HTML content?

Also, are these part of the XML or HTML standard, or a third party standard? And, is there an official site you can point me to about them?

Comment: http://amp-what.com is a good place to look up character entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Character entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)

a number of these are defined in the HTML standard linked above

Answer (score 4):

They are called **character entity references** and defined with slightly varying details(only relevant for exotic ones) in XML, SGML and HTML.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) has a nice overview, whereas the W3C provides the [complete list](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/).

Answer (score 3):

[XHTML Character Entity Reference](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/reference/entity/index.php)

[HTML Entities](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/)